# Render image and mesurements?

Tags: modeling, rendering, workflow, measurement

Trying to figure out how I can get the mesurment tool in blender 2.8 to render with my image?

Answer (score 6):

Blender 2.8 comes with a plugin pre-installed called [MeasureIt](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/3d_view/measureit.html). This allows adding Measurement notations as scene data.  You can then render the annotations separately and composite them back in. In order to get your measurements rendered, all you would have to do is:

1. Click on the <kbd>Render</kbd> button in the Render panel which is going to render your measurements as a separate image based on the active camera
2. Open up a new *Compositor* window or just switch the workspace to Compositing, add an *Image* as well as an *Alpha Over* node
3. Set the image for *Image* node to generated image by the *MeasureIt* add-on
4. Plug your rendering into the upper socket and the generated image into the background (lower) socket of the *Alpha Over* node

[image]

Note: *MeasureIt* is a large and complicated tool, some research is required. I'd suggest have a look into the manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/3d_view/measureit.html or watch some time consuming [youtube tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OoMwmUrOhdc).

Comment: Kirbinator's solution is good! Solved my same question.